# Adding Functionality to the Process All button on the Print Statement Screen(AR503000)

Tags: acumatica

I want to add extra functionality to the Process All button on the Print Statement screen but can't figure it out.

The Override gives me an error.
[image: Screen Error, when opening the Print Statement screen(AR503000)]

The code that I am using that is failing me:

```
public class ARStatementPrint_Extension : PXGraphExtension<ARStatementPrint>
    {
        #region Event Handlers                         
        public delegate void PrintStatementsDelegate();    
        [PXOverride]
        public void PrintStatements(PrintStatementsDelegate baseMethod)
        {
            PXTrace.WriteInformation("This did a thing");
            baseMethod();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The processing delegates are defined in the PrintParameters RowSelected event handler.  Upon inspection of the code, there is a switch statement which defines the method invoked for each action (Print Statement, Do Not Mark, ect)

What you must do is override the RowSelected event handler, and create your own methods to be fired for the action.  For example, you want to do something before or after the Print Statement....

```
public class ARStatementPrint_Extension : PXGraphExtension<PX.Objects.AR.ARStatementPrint>
{

    protected virtual void PrintParameters_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e, PXRowSelected baseMethod)
    {
        //I want to extend the Print action            
        var row = e.Row as PrintParameters;
        PrintParameters filter = Base.Filter.Cache.CreateCopy(row) as PrintParameters;
        switch (row.Action)
        {
            case PrintParameters.Actions.Print:
                Base.Details.SetProcessDelegate(list => ExtendPrintMethod(ref filter, list));
                break;

                //handle the other actions as needed
        }
    }

    private static void ExtendPrintMethod(ref PrintParameters parms, IEnumerable<DetailsResult> list)
    {
        //do something here before the print

        ARStatementPrint.PrintStatements(parms, list);  //call the base method

        //do something here after the print
    }
}
```